# Narrowing in Typescript - possible related to Distributivity?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Simple problem ([playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WGBd0m)):

```js
type C = 'a' | 'b';

type D<T extends C> = {
    prop: T,
}

const something: D<C> = { prop: 'a' };

function funA(arg: D<'a'>) {
}

function funB(arg: D<'b'>) {
}

if (something.prop === 'a') {
    funA(something); // <--- error
}
```

Why can't TS narrow down the type of `something` from `D<C>` to `D<'a'>`?

I assume it's because `D<C> = { prop: 'a' | 'b' }` rather than `D<C> = { prop: 'a' } | { prop: 'b' }`?

Comment: This is due to generics, typescript is not that good with narrowing generics. Alternatively, I can suggest something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwlC8UDkBDJUA+yBGSDcAUAaJFACIA8AKlBAB7AQB2AJgM6wKwB8XN9jVhyoEoUAPxQA3qLFywAJwD2YAFxQqhOVAC+s9UwgA3CAsIEAxkqZtgUNkoC2EYAAsAlkwDm6slylQiirqqOg65gBmAK5MFsDu1lDRTACCABQoCj7kFKHcAJTSegTJcQlMSTEAQhlZvrm4BUVE7hFQaQ7Obp5eAHRBYAjwiKGFMmLJ6Z0uHt75hHpAA). Does this approach work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes `D<C>` (or `D<'a'|'b'>`) is the culprit here. You could declare it as `D<'a'>`, or.. if you remove the type-declaration and instead use a const string literal `'a'` (rather than just the string `'a'`): `const something = { prop: 'a' as const };`, type-inference works as expected.

Comment: It's a missing feature of TS, see [ms/TS#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384).  Guarding a property doesn't narrow the parent object unless that property is the discriminant of a discriminated union... but `{prop: "a" | "b"}` isn't a union at all, let alone a discriminated union, so it doesn't work.  Yes, `{prop: "a"} | {prop: "b"}` *is* a discriminated union, and @wonderflame's suggestion changes it so it is one.  I'll write an answer (or if @wonderflame does so then hopefully they will include a link to the relevant github issue)

Comment: @wonderflame This would work and I think you can post it as an answer with explanation and link provided by jcalz

Comment: I understand the solution provided by wonderflame, but I think it's hard to understand. When I look at my source code in 2 weeks I will probably think: wtf is this ^^ That is, I will most likely replace `D<C>` by `cause D<C> = { prop: 'a' | 'b' } rather than D<C> = { prop: 'a' } | { prop: 'b' }` even though my union has like 50 members ;D but it's definitely easier to follow

Comment: Sure, will post an answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jcalz mentioned in his comment:

> It's a missing feature of TS, see [ms/TS#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384). Guarding a property doesn't narrow the parent object unless that property is the discriminant of a discriminated union... but `{prop: "a" | "b"}` isn't a union at all, let alone a discriminated union, so it doesn't work

The first possible solution would be to not use generics and have the union from the beginning:

```
type D =
  {
    prop: "a";
  } | {
    prop: "b";
  }


const something: D = { prop: 'a' };

function funA(arg: Extract<D, {prop: 'a'}>) { }

function funB(arg: Extract<D, {prop: 'b'}>) { }

if (something.prop === 'a') {
  funA(something);
}
```

This is good to go for the small unions, although the usage of `Extract` may not be the most concise approach so creating separate types for the members of the union would help.

With the generics, we need to [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). Basically, we need to have a condition that is always true to make sure that all members are passing the condition and this will distribute the union. The obvious one is to check `T extends any`, personally, I prefer to use `T extends T`, since it is always true:

```
// {
//     prop: "a";
// } | {
//     prop: "b";
// }
type D<T extends C = C> = T extends T
  ? {
      prop: T;
    }
  : never;
```

Testing:

```
const something: D = { prop: 'a' };

function funA(arg: D<'a'>) {}

function funB(arg: D<'b'>) {}

if (something.prop === 'a') {
  funA(something); // no error
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwlC8UDkBDJUA+yBGSDcAUAaJFACIA8AKlBAB7AQB2AJgM6wKwB8XN9jVhyoEoUAPxQA3qLFywAJwD2YAFxQqhOVAC+s9UwgA3CAsIEAxkqZtgUNkoC2EYAAsAlkwDm6slylQiirqqOg65gBmAK5MFsDu1lDRTACCABQoCj7kFKHcAJTSegTJcQlMSTEAQhlZvrm4BUVE7hFQaQ7Obp5eAHRBYAjwiKGFMmLJ6Z0uHt75eFAA9ItQTEq0CsoKBHpAA)